# when to use using declaration?

Tags: c++, encapsulation, using

I know below `using C1::fn;` will bring fn(...) functions declared in C1 to C2, but I want to know what's the best practice for such `using` in design?

If fn() functions are not using C1 state, should I declare a helper class is the better way?
If fn functions are using C1 state, is `using` breaking encapsulation?

I appreciate if you can even mention some using cases in C++11. Like using the `using Base::Base;` constructor instead of calling it from derived member initializer?

```
class C1
{
  //...
  public:
    int fn(int j) { ... }
    double fn(double w) { ... }
    void fn(const char * s) { ... }
};

class C2 : public C1
{
  //...
public:
  //...
  using C1::fn;
  double fn(double) { ... };
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If fn functions are using C1 state, is using breaking encapsulation?

This `using` statement doesn't break encapsulation; it doesn't expose any `private` state from C1 or prevent C1 maintaining its invariants.  It's purely a convenient way to expose whatever other `fn` members C1 has - in this case `int fn(int)` - so they can be considered when resolving calls.  Think of it as functionally equivalent to...

```
class C2 : public C1
{
    ...
    inline int fn(int j) { return C1::fn(j); }
};
```

...but better because you don't have to manually add and remove functions to keep in sync with C1's list of overloads.

> If fn() functions are not using C1 state, should I declare a helper class is the better way?

If they're not using C1 state, then they should be static or non-members.  Helper classes are an ugly idea in my opinion.  Namespaces are the normal method for grouping functionality in C++.  I'm fully aware of Professor Lakos's recommendations to use classes and understand all the arguments, and still disagree.  Happy to run through it if the mention of helper classes was more than a passing thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should use `using` every time it's needed. That is, every time a member function of a base class gets hidden by one declared in a derived class.

My rationale is that code accessing `C2` (e.g. via `C2 *pc`) knows that `C2` is derived from `C1` and therefore expects to be able to call `C1` functions through `pc`.

Comment: I'd rather say that you should recheck your design every time you feel compelled to use `using` this way. For instance, the example in the question is bad, though I understand that it is just a simple example to illustrate the question.

Comment: @Gorpik Why? This applies even with `virtual` functions. Suppose the base class offers virtual functions overloaded for `int`, `char` and `double`. Derived class needs to redefine `double` variant. Callers of derived class with `int` argument expect to call the `int` one, not the `double` one. See http://ideone.com/kY8pFb

Comment: I know that case, but it is doubtful that, in real apps, you would have those overloads and only need to overwrite the `double` version. In any case, *recheck your design* does not mean *your design is wrong* automatically. In my experience, the need for `using` to uplift base class functions is usually a sign of bad design. There is a reason why the language doesn't do it automatically.